# How to Convert array keys to int

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am using laravel and I Have a array 
this array has keys that some of them are string I want to Change them to int and all of them going to be int

```
$nativeContent = NativeContent::find($id);
$nativeContentView = $nativeContent->countViewNative()
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get()
            ->groupBy(function($date) {
               return Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m'); // grouping by months
            });
```

and my array is like this 
[image]

Comment: In PHP, `"02" == 2` is true, as its a weakly-typed language. You can treat strings-values of integers as integers if you really need to.

Comment: Try using [array_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php). Something like: `$newArray = array_values($oldArray);`

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson it gives me this error array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: @Hassan  it needs to be `$nativeContentView = array_values($nativeContentView);`

Comment: That's because it's a collection object. Turn it into an array first: `array_values($collection->toArray())`

Comment: @ Alive to Die Yeah I know it but still not working and same error

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson thanks a lot it works tnq for your helping

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
->groupBy(function($date) {
            return intval(Carbon::parse($date->created_at)->format('m')); // grouping by months
        });
```